# Declaring a global variable / alias

Tags: prolog

In several places in my prolog code I am using a predicate of the form:

```
node(state([7,0],[11,0]), 0, [], []).
```

Instead of having to retype it every time, I want to associate it to an alias, so that I can rapidly change it in the future without having to change every instance.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple getter through unification.

```
get_some_static(node(state([7,0],[11,0]), 0, [], [])).
```

Now you can call it any time you need as such:

`?- get_some_static(S), do_something(S).`

Variables unify with anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
alias(L1,L2,Value,node(state(L1,L2),Value,[],[])).
```

So every time you call `alias/4`, you can also specify the values from state.

```
solve(A1,A2):-
    L1 = [1,2,3],
    L2 = [4,5,6],
    L3 = [7,8,9],
    L4 = [10,11,12],
    V1 = 0,
    V2 = 0,
    alias(L1,L2,V1,A1),
    alias(L3,L4,V2,A2).

?- solve(A1,A2).
A1 = node(state([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), 0, [], []),
A2 = node(state([7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]), 0, [], [])
```

Comment: Those results don't match what the OP is after. `[[7, 8, 9]]` (a list of one element) is not the same thing as `[7, 8, 9]` (a list of 3 elements). You really want `alias(L1,L2,Value,node(state(L1,L2),Value,[],[])).`

Comment: I like it. It essentially lets you filter out which facts you'd like Prolog try to solve a given problem by filling in the predicate call partially, if you have multiple conditions that partially match with given solutions.